# Best way to split and convert url params into string values

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I would like to split a custom url for app opening in iPhone into values, my scheme would be something like:

```
appname://user=jonsmith&message=blah%20blah
```

Where I would like to be able to get "user" and "message" as two NSStrings. Any advice on best approach?

Comment: As KennyTM pointed out, for my answer to work, you'd need to add a question mark. Better yet add another slash, too: appname:///?user=jonsmith&message=blah%20blah

Comment: No problem - the easier the better :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your url is in an `NSURL` object called `url`:

```
NSMutableDictionary *queryParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSArray *components = [[url query] componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];

for (NSString *component in components) {
    NSArray *pair = [component componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];

    [queryParams setObject:[[pair objectAtIndex:1] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding]
                    forKey:[pair objectAtIndex:0]]; 
}

...

[queryParams release];
```

Comment: Won't work, since his/her URL is `appname://user=jonsmith&message=blah%20blah`, not `appname://?user=jonsmith&message=blah%20blah`. (I agree the latter is a better choice.)

Comment: thank you, this seems like the lowest cost - is there a quick way to reverse url encode the %20 etc?

Comment: I can have my url do as you suggest with the ? query, that's fine :)

Comment: Just edited to add the `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` call

Comment: Note that this doesn't handle any GET parameters that don't have both a key and a value, eg. `http://foo.com?asd`. It will raise an exception when you do `[pair objectAtIndex:1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use Google's `gtm_dictionaryWithHttpArgumentsString` NSDictionary category

http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSDictionary%2BURLArguments.h

Comment: I dislike the naming style of this file, but otherwise it's very well done. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString* yourString = @"appname://user=jonsmith&message=blah%20blah";
NSString* queryString = [yourString substringFromIndex:strlen("appname://")];
NSArray* queryArray = [queryString componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
NSMutableDictionary* queryDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSString* query in queryArray) {
    NSUInteger indexOfEqualsSign = [query rangeOfString:@"="].location;
    if (indexOfEqualsSign != NSNotFound) {
       NSString* key = [[query substringToIndex:indexOfEqualsSign] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       NSString* value = [[query substringFromIndex:indexOfEqualsSign+1] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       [queryDict setObject:value forKey:key];
    }
}
return queryDict;
```

Use an `NSScanner` if you need to save more memory.