# How to remove character between two character in a string?

Tags: xcode, nsstring

i have a string i want remove between character and add character in a string how can i do this?

```
NSString  *strUrl =@"str&mn=12&yr=2012str";
int month =10, int year =2013;
```

i want remove character 12 from `strul` and append 10 same as year between &mn=  &yr

Comment: You are approaching the problem on too low a level; instead write something that will parse those parameters to a dictionary and something which will recreate the url from the parameter dictionary, including doing the URL encoding.

Comment: See
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119640/best-way-to-split-and-convert-url-params-into-string-values

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just want to replace '12' with '10'.

Use stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:

```
NSString  *strUrl = [@"str&mn=12&yr=2012str" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"12" withString:@"10"];
```

Comment: 12 is parser feed value so it is not constant

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you'll use split:

```
var fields = *strUrl.split("&"); //splits the *strurl by "&"
var newString = fields[0]+"&"+fields[1].split("=")[0]+"="+month+fields[2].split("=")[0]+"="+year+"str"; //builds the new assembled string
```

Comment: 12 is  parser feed value so it is not constant

Comment: this solution doesn't treat it as a constant, but uses it's relative location in the string structure you posted.